# How would you handle a Livewire popover?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am looking for a way to make a popover/tooltip in Livewire, preferably without using Vue.

As of now I have created a UserPopover Livewire component with:

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\User;
use Livewire\Component;

class UserPopover extends Component
{
    public $isOpen = false;
    public $user = null;

    protected $listeners = [
        'closeUserPopover',
        'showUserPopover' => 'open',
    ];

    public function open($username)
    {
        $this->user = User::whereName($username)->first();
        $this->isOpen = true;
    }

    public function closeUserPopover()
    {
        $this->isOpen = false;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.user-popover');
    }
}
```

And rendered component:

```
<div>
    @if($isOpen)
        <div class="user-popover fixed top-0 shadow bg-white p-6 text-sm">
            <h3>{{ $user->name }}</h3>
            <div>{{ $user->profile->bio }}</div>
        </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

In my `app.blade.php` file I have included it with `@livewire('user-popover')` and I am calling the component with:

```
<a href="{{ route('users.show', $user) }}"
   wire:mouseover="$emit('showUserPopover', {{ $user->name }})"
   wire:mouseout="$emit('closeUserPopover')"
>
    {{ $user->name }}
</a>
```

I don't know what to do next. Any ideas on positioning, re-usability and overall architecture?

Comment: it seems your code is okay. What do you want now exactly ? want a pop up tool tip when  mouse over with user name?

Comment: Are you not better off doing this in Alpine?

Answer (score 4):

For Example: you can use [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp) tooltip :

Now, you can conditionally render class name (css class contains tooltip styles ) when isOpen is true.

```
<a class="{{ $isOpen ? 'tooltip' : ''  }}" href="{{ route('users.show', $user) }}"
   wire:mouseover="$emit('showUserPopover', {{ $user->name }})"
   wire:mouseout="$emit('closeUserPopover')"
>
    <span class="{{ $isOpen ? 'tooltiptext' : ''  }}"> {{ $user->name }} </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thans for help. A better css is here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_tooltip